# Priority of an OR statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following snippet code:

```
WHERE (Person.WorkGroupId = 2 or Person.RoleId = 2)
```

What I would like to happen is for this to return the first occurrence with a `WorkGroupId` of 2 on Person table. But, if there is not a person with a `WorkgroupId` of 2, then choose the first occurrence with `RoldId` of 2 on the Person table.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want one row returned always? What if two people match this criteria, or one person is in WorkGroupId = 2 and a different person is in RoleId = 2? Can you show sample data, desired results, and the rest of the query? You might have noticed you're getting a bunch of bad answers - this is at least partially because your requirements are very unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I just want the first person who has a workgroupid of 2...if there is no one then I want the first with a roleid of 2...so just one person returned

Comment: Can you clarify that in the question, please?

Comment: Okay I did, hope thats better

Comment: I hope you're paying attention to the dialog that's happened below... also, it may be useful to define what you mean by "first", what indexes exist on the table, and any other filter criteria or joins that might be occurring in the query.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM 
(
  SELECT TOP (1) *, o = 1
  FROM Person
  WHERE WorkGroupId = 2 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT TOP (1) *, o = 2
  FROM Person 
  AND RoleId = 2
) AS x ORDER BY o;
```

Comment: That would scan the Person table 3 times!

Comment: @NirKornfeld flaming answers with stuff like this isn't really necessary. Please note that nobody flamed your answer with the potential for the *possible* sort spill to tempdb that comes with your answer.

Comment: @NirKornfeld Well, I first thought that op wanted one row per person, not one row at all, that's why my answer was this kind of query

Comment: @swasheck I think this site is used mostly for learning purposes. Discussing answers is the way to learn. No need to get offended.

Comment: @NirKornfeld I'm not offended. I find it inappropriate that you put the same comment on every answer as if it was the only factor that affected performance. It just ***seemed*** like you were fishing for upvotes on your answer.

Comment: @swasheck Well, I just put that comment on two answers that used an inner query on that table. I think multiple table scans is one of the most common performance problems on SQL server.

Comment: @nir isn't it funny, though, [when your `sort` operation is more expensive than Lamak's three clustered index scans? (The table has only ~2,100 rows, but still.)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yGf1m.png)

Comment: @NirKornfeld it all depends on the search conditions and the baseline data quantity. A table scan on a big (?) table will (usually) be way better than index seeks returning same number of rows. So discussing the plans, IOs, and real data is OK when actually having that info.

Comment: @AaronBertrand the sort operation will take place **after** the where clause, meaning it will sort the resulting records, and not all the records on the table. To my humble opinion, this approach will be faster.

Comment: @Nir did you look at the link? Your plan requires more I/O (it still has to sort the entire result before the TOP is applied),  and actually is taking longer in every test I've run, with both cold and warm caches. There is no guarantee that your sort will always be faster than other approaches. Please be very careful about blanket statements that imply things like "scans are always bad"...

Comment: @AaronBertrand can you also show the execution plan of my solution? I saw only the triple-scan query.

Comment: @Nir [sure, your plan is simpler, but the metrics don't lie. Lamak's solution uses less CPU, less I/O, and finishes faster. Again, blanket statements, never say never, etc.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7DJod.png) Obviously sorts can be a lot more expensive than you think.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks, is this the estimated or the actual plan? I think we should also check those metrics with larger number of rows in the table...

Comment: @Nir these are actual plans of course, estimated plans are 100% useless (how else could I have collected reads, duration, etc.?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35392/discussion-between-nir-kornfeld-and-aaron-bertrand)

Comment: @Nir Okay, here are the results when dbo.Person has 1,258,600 rows. [Lamak's plan](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b6trx.png), [Your plan](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxu4H.png). Lamak's still wins on duration, CPU, reads. [And also true when I use `MAXDOP 1` to eliminate parallelism from your query](http://i.stack.imgur.com/z25z1.png). This is why assumptions and blanket statements are bad, very bad.

Comment: @Nir also interesting to note: at the larger table size, one of Lamak's scans actually converts to a seek.

Comment: @AaronBertrand There must be a better way to do that than scanning the table 3 times... Maybe sorting on the case expression is the problem. BTW, I saw you've made some major changes in Lamak's original query.

Comment: @Nir not really "major" changes, I just added a TOP 1 and a constant to order by. His original query returned the right row first, it just didn't stop at the first row (since the original requirements in the question were unclear). Is this a problem? Aren't we here for learning purposes, discussing answers, and improving them when appropriate?

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes we are. I think in that case, maybe Lamak's answer should be the accepted one, and not mine.

Comment: @Nir there might be a better way, do you know of one? So far Lamak's performs the best for me. Without knowing anything about the structure of the table, indexes, data skew, ability to change schema or add new indexes, etc. I think it's pretty tough to make any assumptions at this point.

Comment: @Nir FYI I've blogged about this. http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/08/sql-performance/arbitrary-top-1

Answer (score 7):

You would get more than one record if you use just that.

I would do something like:
(The table in question will be scanned only once)

```
Select top 1 *
From dbo.SomeTable
where WorkGroupId=2 or RoleId=2
Order by case 
   when WorkGroupId=2 then 1 
   when RoleId=2 then 2 
end
```

Comment: Sorry but while this query is prettier, [Lamak's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18218741/61305) actually performs better - without knowing anything more about the user's table, of course, and against tables with row counts ranging from 2000 to 1.26 million - as we've proven in the comments below.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Person(
    PersonID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FullName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Col1 INT NOT NULL,
    WorkGroupId TINYINT NOT NULL,
    RoleId TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [Priority] AS CONVERT(TINYINT,              
                CASE  
                    WHEN WorkGroupId=2 THEN 1 -- Priority 1
                    WHEN RoleId=2 THEN 2        -- Priority 2
                    ELSE 3                      -- Priority 3
                END)
);
GO
-- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
SET ARITHABORT ON;
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_Person_Col1_Priority
ON dbo.Person (Col1,[Priority])
INCLUDE (FullName);
GO
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'A'   ,1,1,1);
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'BB'  ,1,0,1);
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'CCC' ,1,2,1); -- <-- 
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'DDDD',1,0,0);
GO
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'X'  ,2,1,1);
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'YY' ,2,1,2); -- <-- 
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'ZZZ',2,1,3);
GO
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'?'   ,3,1,1);
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'!!'  ,3,2,1); -- <-- 
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'%%%' ,3,1,2); 
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'&&&&',3,1,3);
GO
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'-'   ,4,1,1); -- No result
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'--'  ,4,1,1); -- No result
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'---' ,4,1,1); -- No result
INSERT dbo.Person (FullName,Col1,WorkGroupId,RoleId) VALUES (N'----',4,1,1); -- No result
GO

SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT  p.PersonID,p.FullName,
            -- If you have many persons with the same priority then you should use DENSE_RANK
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.[Priority]) AS Rnk
    FROM    dbo.Person p
    WHERE   p.Col1=1
    AND     p.[Priority] IN (1,2)   
) x
WHERE x.Rnk=1;

SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT  p.PersonID,p.FullName,
            -- If you have many persons with the same priority then you should use DENSE_RANK
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.[Priority]) AS Rnk
    FROM    dbo.Person p
    WHERE   p.Col1=2
    AND     p.[Priority] IN (1,2)   
) x
WHERE x.Rnk=1;

SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT  p.PersonID,p.FullName,
            -- If you have many persons with the same priority then you should use DENSE_RANK
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.[Priority]) AS Rnk
    FROM    dbo.Person p
    WHERE   p.Col1=3
    AND     p.[Priority] IN (1,2)   
) x
WHERE x.Rnk=1;

SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT  p.PersonID,p.FullName,
            -- If you have many persons with the same priority then you should use DENSE_RANK
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.[Priority]) AS Rnk
    FROM    dbo.Person p
    WHERE   p.Col1=4 
    AND     p.[Priority] IN (1,2)
) x
WHERE x.Rnk=1;
```

Results:

```
PersonID FullName Rnk
-------- -------- ---
3        CCC      1


PersonID FullName Rnk
-------- -------- ---
6        YY       1


PersonID FullName Rnk
-------- -------- ---
9        !!       1


PersonID FullName Rnk
-------- -------- ---
```

And the execution plan for the last four statements is:
[image]

Note: `Col1` represents the test num.

Comment: This works ok if you can change the table and probably you'll need to persist and index that column as well. If you move the expression to the ROW_NUMBER() calculation, you introduce the same expensive sort operation present in Nir's answer.